# How to replace object fields by content of nested field?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is my object, which I need to modify:

```
const doc = { 
  _id: 'ZjenyEXyLChbksHqL',
  content: {
    en: [
      { 
        content: 'Content',
        timestamp: 1518811796,
        reviewed: { 
          user: '5b0b9e1153e8a750642e9caf',
          timestamp: 1518811796
        },
        finalized: { 
          user: '5b0b9e1153e8a750642e9caf',
          timestamp: 1518811796
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  reference: [ 'hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi' ],
  main: 'XN7iqmCFD4jpgJZ6f'
}
```

I need to replace the content object by the first object of the `en`-array.

The result should look like:

```
{ 
  _id: 'ZjenyEXyLChbksHqL',
  content: 'Content',
  reviewed: { 
    user: '5b0b9e1153e8a750642e9caf',
    timestamp: 1518811796
  },
  finalized: { 
    user: '5b0b9e1153e8a750642e9caf',
    timestamp: 1518811796
  },
  reference: [ 'hp9v53uQqQPRXSYAi' ],
  main: 'XN7iqmCFD4jpgJZ6f'
}
```

My attempt looks like this:

```
const language = 'en'
const data = (doc && doc.content && doc.content[language] && doc.content[language][0]) || {}
doc.content = data.content
doc.reviewed = data.reviewed
doc.finalized = data.finalized
```

That feels not very elegant. Couldn't I use a spread-operator or something like this?

Also my problem is, that `reviewed` and `finalized` are optional. In that case I don't want to set that key.
In my code I do get `finalized: undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.assign(doc, ((doc.content || {})[language] || [{}])[0])
```

You could use Object.assign to copy all the values. That might be a bit more elegant using an utility:

```
const get = (obj, ...keys) => keys.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] || {}, obj);

Object.assign(doc, get(doc, "content", language, 0));
```

Comment: If I want to replace `reviewed` and `finalized` by a boolean value (true if objects exists, and false if not), would that also be possible? Because this is not just copying the fields.

Comment: @user3142695 then you would have to do `doc.reviewed = !!doc.reviewed` after copying

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the spread operator.

```
const data = (doc && doc.content && doc.content[language] && doc.content[language][0]) || {}

const newDoc = {
    ...doc,
    ...data
}
```